# Differentiability of the function defined by $\sum_{n\geq 1 } \sin n^2 x / n^{5/2} $

Tags: derivatives, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

It is known that the Riemann function

$$ \sum_{n\geq 1 } \frac{\sin n^2 x }{n^2} $$

is differentiable only at countably many points.

How about the functions

$$\sum_{n\geq 1 } \frac{\sin n^2 x}{n^{5/2}}, \quad\;\; \sum_{n\geq 1 } \frac{\cos n^2 x}{n^{5/2}} ?  $$

I plotted their graphs by taking the first 100000 terms. It is not so suggestive.

The problem can of course be generalized to other exponents.

[image]